# Looking for a PHP based Revision Difference Comparison

Tags: php, diff

I've been trying to figure this one out for a bit... I even downloaded MediaWiki and looked at their diff script, but I couldn't make heads or tails out of it. I am making a content management system, that will have revision history saved on it. However, revision history is pointless unless you can analyze the difference. I have very simplistic needs beyond that, and a lot of systems out there are very complicated, and I am nowhere near smart enough to figure them out.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Diff

I want to input two variables:

- $old (which is the source code of the left)
- $new (which is the source code of the right)

Then I want to receive back an array matrix of results. Each element of the array is a row, like what you see in the wikipedia link above. Each element should have 4 values...

- $oldDiff (which will be the modifier of the left, usually blank, + or -)
- $newDiff (which will be the modifier of the right, usually blank, + or -)
- $oldLine (the line of text for the left)
- $newLine (the line of text for the right)

Thats it... pretty simple results. I can analyze the array matrix myself and output the results within my script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using PHP-Diff by Chris Boulton
https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-diff

It worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Pear [`Text_Diff`](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Diff/) package.  It won't give you exactly the arrays you want, but it will give something you should be able to use.  You may also want to look into the native UNIX `diff` utility, which will without doubt be faster than any native PHP method.

Comment: I've look at Text_Diff before... and it confused me. I have absolutely no idea how to use it.